# How to automatically set height of UICollectionViewCell to fit content

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a UICollectionView that has a bunch of cells that contain content of different heights. How can I go about having the cells automatically grow to be the height of their content?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if there is an automatic way of doing this like using UITableViewAutomaticDimension other than using autolayout constraints

What you could do is to create a constraint property

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSLayoutConstraint *heightConstraint;
```

Then calculate the content size of the cell after creating it and in `updateConstraints` update the heightConstraint constant

```
self.heightConstraint.constant = calculatedHeight;
```

Finally whenever you have updated the content call to `setNeedsUpdateConstraints`

Answer (score 0):

http://code4app.net/ios/FBLikeLayout/54f17bdbe247418102a8f6e4

Here is a link that shows an example project with different size CollectionCell Heights.